# LSTM/RNN seems to be failing at testing

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, lstm, rnn

I'm relatively new to ML, keras and tensorflow and I working with a dataset (kerastest.csv) that is 400 lines of this

```
sequence,target
0.54701155 0.517513 0.4690355 0.48752165 0.46766028 0.5972366 0.61058664 0.7067254 0.7121893 0.7661711 0.77721995 0.7518825 0.68164456 0.5985321,1
0.551435 0.5153954 0.4721298 0.490865 0.47131577 0.60469216 0.6038976 0.7038085 0.7110235 0.77294403 0.7816415 0.7592487 0.67063993 0.6062528,1
0.55585843 0.5132778 0.4752241 0.49420834 0.47497123 0.6121478 0.5972085 0.70089155 0.70985764 0.7797169 0.78606296 0.7666148 0.65963525 0.61397344,1
0.5483472 0.51139927 0.4748516 0.48613134 0.47298145 0.6120353 0.5916382 0.6981726 0.69980276 0.7783837 0.78754336 0.7675861 0.6592715 0.6162258,0
0.5351824 0.5096339 0.47283685 0.47264448 0.46831745 0.6083377 0.58659786 0.6955476 0.6855371 0.77321047 0.7876306 0.7655281 0.66394836 0.61588776,0
0.52201766 0.50786847 0.47082213 0.45915762 0.46365345 0.6046401 0.5815576 0.69292253 0.67127144 0.76803726 0.7877178 0.7634701 0.6686252 0.61554974,0
0.56658393 0.49670732 0.4596451 0.49459377 0.507614 0.5795203 0.6221169 0.7199565 0.6908693 0.75352824 0.74981964 0.7737604 0.70846057 0.5648611,1
0.5691148 0.49902853 0.45811677 0.4862831 0.507614 0.5830465 0.630378 0.72070897 0.69663626 0.7547129 0.75281024 0.7726751 0.71151966 0.56712264,1
```

My code looks like this

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, Embedding
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


input_file = 'kerastest.csv'


def load_data(test_split = 0.2):
    print ('Loading data...')
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
    df['sequence'] = df['sequence'].apply(lambda x: [float(e) for e in x.split()])
    df = df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))

    train_size = int(len(df) * (1 - test_split))

    X_train = df['sequence'].values[:train_size]
    y_train = np.array(df['target'].values[:train_size])
    X_test = np.array(df['sequence'].values[train_size:])
    y_test = np.array(df['target'].values[train_size:])

    return pad_sequences(X_train), y_train, pad_sequences(X_test), y_test


def create_model(input_length):
    print ('Creating model...')
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim = 188, output_dim = 50, input_length = input_length))
    model.add(LSTM(activation="sigmoid", return_sequences=True, units=256, recurrent_activation="hard_sigmoid"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(LSTM(activation="sigmoid", units=256, recurrent_activation="hard_sigmoid"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    print ('Compiling...')
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_data()

model = create_model(len(X_train[0]))

print ('Fitting model...')
hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=10, validation_split = 0.1, verbose = 1)

score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=1)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```

My output (10 epochs though increasing it does't change anything) looks like

```
Loading data...
Creating model...
Compiling...
Fitting model...
Train on 288 samples, validate on 32 samples
Epoch 1/10
288/288 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7022 - acc: 0.7396 - val_loss: 1.4764 - val_acc: 0.2812
Epoch 2/10
288/288 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5812 - acc: 0.7569 - val_loss: 1.0761 - val_acc: 0.2812
Epoch 3/10
288/288 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5750 - acc: 0.7500 - val_loss: 1.3237 - val_acc: 0.2812
Epoch 4/10
288/288 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5648 - acc: 0.7604 - val_loss: 1.2321 - val_acc: 0.2812
Epoch 5/10
288/288 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5900 - acc: 0.7500 - val_loss: 1.1174 - val_acc: 0.2812
Epoch 6/10
288/288 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6045 - acc: 0.7465 - val_loss: 1.3299 - val_acc: 0.2812
Epoch 7/10
288/288 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5820 - acc: 0.7604 - val_loss: 1.3163 - val_acc: 0.2812
Epoch 8/10
288/288 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5778 - acc: 0.7604 - val_loss: 1.1562 - val_acc: 0.2812
Epoch 9/10
288/288 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5938 - acc: 0.7604 - val_loss: 0.8883 - val_acc: 0.2812
Epoch 10/10
288/288 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5779 - acc: 0.7535 - val_loss: 1.4051 - val_acc: 0.2812
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step
Test score: 1.8908673524856567
Test accuracy: 0.0
```

So my question is, have I royally screwed up somewhere in configuring the network because I presume a 50% testing accuracy is just about random, but 0% testing accuracy means I must have screwed something up somewhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: May I know the reason for you to use embedding and sequencial architecture

Comment: Should I be avoiding the use of both at once?

Comment: No, You can use both at a time. I was not able to correlate your data with your architecture, that's why I asked. Can you also check the prediction values whether they coming as same value?